# How to check if the file is flash or image file in PHP?

Tags: php, flash

I need to check if the file which exist is the flash file or the image file,  so i can put the file in **Object** tag or **img** tag respectively.

Comment: By extension? strpos('.flv')? OR http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

Comment: What did your research / search here on SO come up with? Why didn't that work for you?

Comment: Check either mime type or extension simply...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use $_FILES['file_name']['type']; and it will return you file type that you can check alternatively you can use

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("profilepic/".$db_question_data[$lpcntrl]['Photo']);
```

it will also return you file type of tile in **$type** variable.
Hope this help :)

Comment: Knowing a file type wont help as, If tomorrow some different extension for flash comes than it will surly break my code.  I Need something for long term.

Comment: You are right, but you need not to worry about that because $_FILES['file_name']['types'] will return mime type not actual extension, so even if extension will get change, mime type will remain same. i.e.video/x-flv

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get extensions of files from its file name. And can check this file is image or flash using Conditional statement **IF** as below

```
<?php
$filename ="file.jpg";

$ext = strtolower(array_pop(explode('.',$filename)));
    if ($ext=='swf'){
    echo "flash";//set your object as flash
    }
    else{
    echo "image";//set your object as img
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathinfo` for this like below:

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo($filepath);

echo $path_parts['extension']; // You can get the file extension for this
?>
```